# Download latest file from Github folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

how would I download the latest file that is uploaded to some Github repo in a particular folder? I am using Node.js with cron job to download the file, but I need to get the fresh file every day.

This is the repo if anyone is interested: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous day's reports are published every day, so get the latest file using the date.

```js
function getDate() {
 const yesterday = new Date();
 yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
 let dd = yesterday.getDate(); 
 let mm = yesterday.getMonth() + 1; 
 const yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear(); 
 if (dd < 10) { 
     dd = '0' + dd; 
 } 
 if (mm < 10) { 
     mm = '0' + mm; 
 } 
 return `${mm}-${dd}-${yyyy}`
}

const baseUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/';

function getLatestDownloadUrl() {
 return `${baseUrl}${getDate()}.csv`;
}

console.log(getLatestDownloadUrl());
```